# SQL Replace in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Any idea why this snippet of HQL would be failing.. REPLACE function requires three arguments is the error. Is there any other way to perform a replace in HQL>?

"`WHERE :url LIKE ('%' || REPLACE(atf.title,'*','') || '%')"  +`

Comment: Hi, what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I didn't understand :url, shouldn't it like - "where url like .. " ?

Comment: :url is a replacement string used elsewhere in the code. The Error is as stated:

"REPLACE function requires three arguments"

Comment: refactored entire thing to get around it. was a better way to solve.

Answer (score 1):

HQL does not support REPLACE function.

So you have to make your own custom dialect and register REPLACE function into it throught **Dialect::registerFunction** method

For example i am registering REPLCAE in postgres dialect like in next code

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;

public class MyPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

    public MyPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("replace", new StandardSQLFunction("replace"));
    }
}
```

then refer to this custom dialect in your persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml file